# Query string syntax for exact match against array field?

Tags: elasticsearch

suppose we have a type Documents with field tags that stores a JSON 
array. a couple of Documents' tags values may therefore be:

```
1) [ "casestudy", "article"] 
2) [ "article" ]
```

what query would return docs whose tags contain solely "article" 
(thus only return #2 from the above set)? I thought query string / field 
query would work but using: 
tags:"article" also returns #1.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to create another field (e.g. called `tags_length`) that contains the length of the `tags` array. Then you'll be able to query for `tags:"article" AND tags_length:1`

Comment: Thanks @Val for your response, I have huge data in elasticsearch which will require the data migration. So I have resolved this query issue with different approach.

Comment: Maybe you can share what you've done in an answer so that might help others with the same or a similar issue.